# Who sent Winston Baldry as a fake Leroy to kill Jerry?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mexican

In [*The Mexican*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0236493/) (2001), who send Winston Baldry masquerading as Leroy to Kill Jerry?

"Leroy" befriended Jerry's lover Samantha.

But Jerry shoots Leroy/Baldry in the head as he knows he's an imposter.

He thinks the imposter has been sent to kill him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bernie Nayman

Margolese's second-in-command sent Baldry (who masquerades as Leroy) so that he could sell the gun instead of returning it to the rightful owner as Margolese intends.

Jerry figures it out...

> " 'Give the gun to Leroy. He'll get it down to Margolese.' Ha-fucking-ha!"
>
> "You see? Do you see?"
>
> "I'm being set up!"
>
> "Nayman hires this prick to take out Leroy, get the gun and pin it all on Jackoff Jerry."

Margolese says..

> "I had Nayman send you down here, but **I didn't know he was looking for a buyer.** When I found out he was looking for a buyer, I didn't know who on my team was... still on my team, or even if there was a goddamn team."

Comment: Thank You, I also didn't understand what is the use of "Margolese" in the movie?

Comment: Margolese was a character's last name.  Like a notorious mobster Al Capone is simple referred to as "Capone" without the first name